# Reds key: use `table:<id>:col1` or use hashes?

Tags: redis

When converting a relational database to a redis database, should we use

```
table:<id>:col1
table:<id>:col2
table:<id>:coln
```

as keys or use hashes instead, for example

```
table:col1 = { <id1>: <value1>, <id2>: <value2>, ... }
table:col2 = { <id1>: <value1>, <id2>: <value2>, ... }
table:coln = { <id1>: <value1>, <id2>: <value2>, ... }
```

And why?

Comment: You should not **convert** or **replace** a relational DB to redis, You should design your redis solution based on how the data needs to be retrieved. See [this](http://liamkaufman.com/blog/2012/06/04/redis-and-relational-data/)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably thinking about this the wrong way.

In Redis, you store the data according to the way you want to fetch it. First think about your queries, then decide on the "schema".

In any case, the Hash approach is usually used both to keep related value grouped together (like columns in a row) as well reduce the per-key overhead.

Based on the very broad information the OP had provided, if we assume `<id>` to be a row identifier, a.k.a the primary key, what would make sense to me is:

```
HMSET table:<id> col1 <value1> col2 <value2> ...
```

But that structure doesn't ensure that any data would be fetch effectively, excluding the equivalent of `SELECT/UPDATE/DELETE (somecolumn or *) from table WHERE id=<id>`.

So, what are the queries that your database has to serve?